# How to keep a Foreground service alive, even under pressure?

Tags: android, broadcast, foreground-service

I want to make an app with a Broadcast Receiver. I read a lot in this topic and I understood that a Foreground service is the best for the task. It is **REALLY** important for the Broadcast Receiver to be active always and forever. The problem I am facing with is that the Foreground service works well until 24 hours from the moment it has been started, and after 24 hours the foreground is getting killed. The Foreground is also getting killed when my phone is under load, like when playing a heavy 3D game.

I have tried a lot (and I mean, a **lot**) of ways to overcome this obstacle, and some of them made things better, but not perfectly and not the way I want them to work.

My test phone is the Xiaomi Redmi Note 10, with android 11. From what I read, if I'll be able to find the solution for Xiaomi phones, I'll find the solution for all of the phones (I read that Xiaomi are the worst with all of that battery optimization stuff).

How can I keep my Foreground service alive even when my phone is under pressure?

Is there a better way to keep a Broadcast Receiver working and "listening"?

***The way I start the Service in my Activity:***

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            startForegroundService(intent);
        }else{
            startService(intent);
        }
```

***My Service code:***

```
public class MyService extends Service {


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        createNotificationChannle();

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "ChannelID1")
                .setContentTitle("No More Spam Calls!")
                .setContentText("We Are Protecting You.")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void createNotificationChannle() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    "ChannelID1", "Foreground notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(intent);
        } else {
            startService(intent);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't, not under modern Android.  What is your BroadcastReceiver doing?  SOmetimes you can put it in the Manifest and be automatically called by the OS.

Comment: My Broadcast is a phone call broadcast.